# How to select unique values for a column where the IDs are different?

Tags: oracle, select, distinct

I have a select statement that is returning an ID column and value column. The values in the ID column are distinct, but there are duplicates in the value column.

Here is an example:

```
    ID    |    Value
-----------------------
    1     |     Bob
    2     |     Jane
    3     |     Bob
    4     |     Mike
    5     |     Suzy
    6     |     Mike
```

As you can see there are 4 unique name values but 6 records returned because the IDs are all different. This normally should not be done, but this is just example data (not really using names) and for what I need to do I need to remove records with duplicate names.

I was trying to use the lead or lag function but couldn't get it to remove the duplicates.

Any ideas on how to modify a straight forward select statement to get both columns but with only unique names?

Comment: Which `ID` value should the query choose when there are more than one having the same `value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This deletes recorde with duplicate names, but leaves the first record with lowest id.

```
DELETE FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT null FROM table t1
   WHERE t.name = t1.name AND t.id < t1.id
)
```

If you only want to select records, then

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT null FROM table t1
   WHERE t.name = t1.name AND t.id < t1.id
)
```

Comment: OP didn't actually ask for anything to be deleted.

Comment: @ Mick Mnemonic sorry, I Thought that `get it to remove the duplicates` meant `I want to delete records`, You are right, I was wrong.

Comment: The select statement works perfect. I needed that exists part. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be curious about performance with these self-anti-joins... A `GROUP BY` solution has a bigger chance to be done entirely in memory in most databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), Value
FROM table
GROUP BY Value
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Value), Value
FROM table
```